# Form margin-left won't working

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a contact form and I've the an issue; I want to give the form a margin-left of 20px. But the browser is disable the style. See the pic

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/disabled-style.jpg]

Please check the live page here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/Contact/contact.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contact.css:205

```
form { margin-left: 20px; }
```

Modify as follows:

```
.contact > form { margin-left: 20px; }
```